# Mix numbers and strings in same column

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have a table that has both numbers and strings in one column. How can I use `pgfplotstable` to display them both?

Of course, one way would be to simple delete the strings:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
columns/Iterations/.style={string replace={DIVERGED}{}}]
{
  Iterations
  1421
  DIVERGED
  5362
}

\end{document}
```

But what I really want is to use the neat number formatting capabilities of `pgfplots` together with displaying the string `DIVERGED` at certain rows, as shown above.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your string type cells have always only `DIVERGED` as text, you can simply add `empty cells with={DIVERGED}` to your code and it works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        columns/Iterations/.style={string replace={DIVERGED}{}},
        empty cells with={DIVERGED}
        ] {
            Iterations
            1421
            DIVERGED
            5362
        }

\end{document}
```

[image]